# sudo apt-get update error etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt-get update 

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 https://cli.github.com/packages focal InRelease                         
Ign:4 https://deb.leap.se/client release InRelease                            
Hit:5 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                     
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease               
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease              
Hit:12 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]      
Err:14 https://deb.leap.se/client release Release                             
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 204.13.164.163 443]
Hit:15 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease           
Hit:16 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Ign:11 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease               
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:18 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Get:19 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg [1,652 B]
Ign:19 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.leap.se/client release Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
E: The repository 'http://http.debian.net/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list:2
```

error deb:

```
Command 'deb' not found, did you mean:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. install `leap-archive-keyring`

   `sudo apt install leap-archive-keyring`
2. remove debian repository `http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian`.
3. remove duplicate entry for `signal` repository from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`